# Índice fuera de intervalo

Tags: c#, sql-server, checkbox, datagridview

Cargo un **DataGridView** con datos de **SQLServer** que son (id, nombre, celular, url) de los cuales necesito guardar en una lista los **celulares, url** para utilizarlos luego, agregué **CheckBoxes** para seleccionar alguno de esos items o todos los cuales se encargan de almacenar en una lista los datos mencionados anteriormente. 
Ha surgido un problema que si bien puedo seleccionar uno o varios items, al presionar el **Botón** sale este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código de selección de **CheckBoxes:**

```
List<string> celulares = new List<string>();
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dtgId.Rows){
                var ch1 = new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell();
                ch1 = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells[4];
                celulares.Add(row.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
                if (ch1.Value == null){
                    ch1.Value = false;
                }//para almacenar los celulares en la lista por medio del CheckBox

List<string> urls = new List<string>();
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dtgId.Rows)
            {
                if ((bool)row.Cells[4].Value)
                {
                    urls.Add(row.Cells[3].Value.ToString());//columna donde estan las urls
                }
            }//para almacenar las urls en las listas por medio del CheckBox
```

Aquí es donde sale el error:

```
for (int i = 0; i < celulares.Count; i++){
                bloque = bloque + "ID" + Convert.ToInt32(contador) + "\t" + celulares[i] + "\t" + urls[i] + "\n";//en esta línea sale el error
                Console.WriteLine(bloque);
            }
```

Código completo del **Botón:**

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

            List<string> celulares = new List<string>();
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dtgId.Rows){
                var ch1 = new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell();
                ch1 = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells[4];
                celulares.Add(row.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
                if (ch1.Value == null){
                    ch1.Value = false;
                }
            }

            List<string> urls = new List<string>();
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dtgId.Rows)
            {
                if ((bool)row.Cells[4].Value)
                {
                    urls.Add(row.Cells[3].Value.ToString());//columna donde estan las urls
                }
            }

            //Codigo para enviar SMS
            string usuario = "usuario";
            string clave = "clave";
            string respuesta = ""; 
            string texto = txtTexto.Text;
            string bloque = "";
            contador++;
            for (int i = 0; i < celulares.Count; i++){
                bloque = bloque + "ID" + Convert.ToInt32(contador) + "\t" + celulares[i] + "\t" + urls[i] + "\n";//en esta línea sale el error
            }

            Uri uri = new Uri("uri");

            HttpWebRequest requestFile = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            requestFile.Method = "POST";
            requestFile.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
            postData.Append("api=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("1") + "&");
            postData.Append("usuario=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(usuario) + "&");
            postData.Append("clave=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(clave) + "&");
            postData.Append("separadorcampos=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("tab") + "&");
            postData.Append("bloque=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(bloque) + "&");

            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData.ToString());//no comentar

            requestFile.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            Stream requestStream = requestFile.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            requestStream.Close();
            HttpWebResponse webResp = requestFile.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            if (requestFile.HaveResponse)
            {
                if (webResp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK || webResp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Accepted)
                {
                    StreamReader respReader = new StreamReader(webResp.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));
                    respuesta = respReader.ReadToEnd();
                    MessageBox.Show(respuesta);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si miras el código, es normal que pete...

Por una parte tienes una lista de celulares que siempre agrega un item
10 celulares = 10 items en la lista

Sin embargo, por otro lado tienes una lista de url, pero, está filtrada de esta forma:

```
    if ((bool)row.Cells[4].Value)
    {
            urls.Add(row.Cells[3].Value.ToString());//columna donde estan las urls
    }
```

Si no hay url no hace el Add por lo tanto
puede (que es lo que te pasa) que existan 5 url...

Entonces, cuando vas a buscar la url del telefono 8 si tu lista de url es 5 cuando el indice vale 6 pues se va fuera de rango...

Saludos.